# As a total beginner, need to make a javascript search function not case sensitive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am really new to programming and trying to make my first site using the basics. I am trying to do a search/filter bar to search/filter through the set of images on my web. Lets go with "Josh". If I search "Josh", it finds it, but if I search "josh" or "JOsh" it does not.

```
 function search(){
  var searchText = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img");
  
  if(searchText.length > 0){
    images.forEach((image) => {
      image.classList.add("hide");
      if(image.dataset.tags.indexOf(searchText) > -1){
        image.classList.remove("hide");
      }
    });
  }else{
    images.forEach((image) => {
        image.classList.remove("hide");
    });
  }
}
```

I tried using the .toLowerCase() before .indexOf but that just makes all the search lowercase and if I try to use it somewhere else it just straight up does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi newts! Welcome to SO and welcome to programming. What happens when you try `toLowerCase()` why is it that it just straight up does not work?

Comment: please provide a minimal html as well so we can help you

Comment: you need to *normalize* the string, either to upper or lower case.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Nina Scholz, you need to normalize the string.

Your initial move was partially correct, you stated that you had used  `.toLowerCase() before .indexOf`, what you need to do, is to also make the search value input lowercase. Then everything will work as intended.

```js
function search(){
 //Normalize your search text to lowercase
  var searchText = (document.getElementById("searchInput").value).toLowerCase();
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img");
  
  if(searchText.length > 0){
    images.forEach((image) => {
      image.classList.add("hide");
      //Normalize your search targets to lowercase
      if((image.dataset.tags).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1){
        image.classList.remove("hide");
      }
    });
  }else{
    images.forEach((image) => {
        image.classList.remove("hide");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for **strings** you can use regular expression that match your input no matter if its lower or upper and use **search** method instead of **indexOf**, this is how you can do it:

```
function search(){
    var searchText = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
    var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img");
    var regex = new RegExp(searchText, "i");

    if(searchText.length > 0){
      images.forEach((image) => {
        image.classList.add("hide");
        if(image.dataset.tags.search(regex) > -1){
          image.classList.remove("hide");
        }
      });
    }else{
      images.forEach((image) => {
          image.classList.remove("hide");
      });
    }
}
```

for **arrays** you need to use **test** method instead of **search** as follows

```
if(arr.map(el => regex.test(el)){
  //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.indexOf()` in this case.
You could use the array function [`some()` (mdn link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

There are many ways of achieving what you want here. Personally, I wouldn't use `forEach` or `some` at all; they are 100x - 1000x slower than just using a `for(){}` loop. (But if you only have a few images with a couple tags or something, it won't matter.)

```
function search(){
    var searchTextLowerCase = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();
    var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img");
    
    if(searchTextLowerCase.length > 0){
      images.forEach((image) => {
        image.classList.add("hide");
        if( image.dataset.tags.some( tag => tag.toLowerCase() === searchTextLowerCase ) ){
          image.classList.remove("hide");
        }
      });
    }else{
      images.forEach((image) => {
          image.classList.remove("hide");
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you not be able to use an `indexOf`? And do you have any evidence for the performance claim? It seems quite unlikely.

Comment: @DBS `indexOf` can't change the case of the tags or accept regular expressions. It is always case-sensitive, so he cannot use it. I've run performance tests for Array functions within the last two months as part of research for a TC39 proposal. In both Chrome and Firefox, function calls have a *very* high overhead, which makes `forEach` and `some` extremely slow compared to a loop with no function calls. (Same for `Map.get( key )` vs `Obj[ key ]`, etc.) Of course, if you care, do the tests yourself. Respectfully, if you don't care enough to check, then don't pretend to know.

Comment: Obviously the `indexOf` doesn't change the case itself, but neither does your approach, they both rely on `toLowerCase()` so I'm not sure what your point is there. Regarding "if you don't care enough to check, then don't pretend to know" I expressed doubt and asked for evidence, I clearly did not pretend to be certain. Please don't take it personally when asked to explain a claim on a site intended to educate.

Comment: @DBS (Edit: I did say "personally", so it was a personal thing, I guess?) I created large objects, arrays, typed arrays, sets, and maps, (>1 million entries), then made functions to assign / read entries, with fixed keys and random keys, using various access methods, using performance.now() to record how long each access method took, then compiled all the results in tables and repeated the process for Chrome and Firefox (and Edge, Opera, Brave, and Chromium, which all matched Chrome.) `toLowerCase()` changes case. I'll leave it at that and check out of the conversation here.

Answer (score 0):

Make both `upper case` or both `lower case`, then find index of searchText in tag